# Kendo Grid - How to disable cascaded dropdownlistfor when in edit mode and enable it when add mode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I would like to disable the `DropDownListFor` which is cascading from another dropdownlist in editor while editing a record and keep it enable while in adding a record. I am using Kendo Grid in my MVC project.

Here I would like to disable Country Dropdownlist and location dropdownlist when in edit mode and keep enable when in add(insert new record) mode

The code is as below:

Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Webapplication1.Models.mainViewModel>()
    .Name("mainGrid")
    .Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Bound(m => m.Id).Hidden();
        c.Bound(m => m.CountryViewModel.CountryName)
            .Title("Country").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Countries" });
        c.Bound(m => m.LocationViewModel.LocationName)
            .Title("Location").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Locations" });
        c.Command(p =>
        {p.Edit().Text(" ").UpdateText(" ").CancelText(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Edit" });});
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => { toolbar.Create().Text("").HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Add"}); })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("gridEditor"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
        .PageSize(10)
        .Read(read => read.Action("mainGrid_Read", "abc"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("mainGrid_Update", "abc"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("mainGrid_Create", "abc"))
        .Model(m => { m.Id(p => p.Id);
          m.Field(p => p.CountryViewModel).DefaultValue(ViewData["DefaultCountry"] as Webapplication1.Models.CountryViewModel);      
        })
    )
)
```

Country DropDownList:

```
@model Webapplication1.Models.CountryViewModel

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .AutoBind(false)
    .OptionLabel("Select")
    .DataValueField("CountryId")
    .DataTextField("CountryName") 
    .DataSource(dataSource =>
                  {
                      dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("GetCountries", "abc").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
                                .ServerFiltering(true);
                  })
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)
```

Location DropDownList:

```
@model Webapplication1.Models.LocationViewModel

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .OptionLabel("Select")
    .DataValueField("LocationId")
    .DataTextField("LocationName")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .DataSource(d =>
    {
        d.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetLocationsByCountryId", "abc").Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("getCountryId");
        }).ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .CascadeFrom("CountryViewModel")
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)
```

Popup editor:

```
@model Webapplication1.Models.mainViewModel
<table>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("Country:")</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CountryViewModel)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("Location:")</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.LocationViewModel)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: By the way, your code looks so strange. Where's the other drop-down list?   What else is in your ViewModel? How come you are using the drop-down list like `DropDownListFor(m => m)`? Is this inside and EditorTemplate?

Comment: @ataravati: yes dropdownlists are inside popup editor. I think if I change the edit mode to InLine, it should not make any difference. I have editied the code here and posted grid, dropdownlist editors and popup editor code now.

Comment: I never said change the edit mode to InLine. What seems so unnecessary is having EditorTemplates for Country and Location.

Answer (score 0):

Add an Edit event to your grid like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Webapplication1.Models.mainViewModel>()
    .Name("mainGrid")
    .Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Bound(m => m.Id).Hidden();
        c.Bound(m => m.CountryViewModel.CountryName)
            .Title("Country").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Countries" });
        c.Bound(m => m.LocationViewModel.LocationName)
            .Title("Location").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Locations" });
        c.Command(p =>
        {p.Edit().Text(" ").UpdateText(" ").CancelText(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Edit" });});
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => { toolbar.Create().Text("").HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Add"}); })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("gridEditor"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
        .PageSize(10)
        .Read(read => read.Action("mainGrid_Read", "abc"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("mainGrid_Update", "abc"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("mainGrid_Create", "abc"))
        .Model(m => { m.Id(p => p.Id);
          m.Field(p => p.CountryViewModel).DefaultValue(ViewData["DefaultCountry"] as Webapplication1.Models.CountryViewModel);      
        })
    )
    .Events(events => events.Edit("onEdit"))
)
```

And, add this script to your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onEdit(e) {
        //if current model is new (add)...
        if (e.model.isNew()) {            
            e.container.find("#CountryViewModel").data("kendoDropDownList").enable();            
        }
        else
        {
            e.container.find("#CountryViewModel").data("kendoDropDownList").enable(false);            
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

By the way, you don't have to create ViewModels for Country and Location. You can use `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to create your drop-down lists. Also, no need to create EditorTemplates. Put your drop-down lists directly in your View.

**UPDATE:**

Make sure your Location drop-down list is disabled by default. Then, you'll have to enable/disable the Country drop-down list.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .OptionLabel("Select")
    .DataValueField("LocationId")
    .DataTextField("LocationName")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .DataSource(d =>
    {
        d.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetLocationsByCountryId", "abc").Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("getCountryId");
        }).ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .CascadeFrom("CountryViewModel")
    .Enable(false)
)
```

Comment: This not working. It is working only for Country dropdownlist and no working for Location dropdownlist. I still can change the values in Location dropdownlist.

Comment: How's that possible man? Just look at the source code, and see if the location drop-down list's `id` matches the one in the script. If it works for one, it should work for the other too. It's the same thing.

Comment: Well the id is same "LocationViewModel" here. I think it is because of .CascadeFrom("CountryViewModel") in it. I mean Location dropdownlist is cascade from country dropdownlist that's why it should handl differantly.

Comment: Try my updated answer and see if it works. Note that the script has also been updated.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I just realized that you have a default value for the Country DropDownList. That automatically enables the cascading DropDownList. Remove the default value to see if it works.

Comment: I have noticed a strange behaviour here. I have created an event in Country DropDownList as .Events(e =>e.Cascade("onCascadeLocation")) and then disable the Location DropDownList in this event as function onCascade() { alert("cascading");
$("#LocationViewModel").data("kendoDropDownList").enable(false);
    }. Very strangely, when I put Alert herr it works fine and disable the Location dropdown but  when I remove alert, it is not disabling the Location DropDown. Why?

Comment: Expert's any comment on this? @ataravati

Comment: Add `e.preventDefault()` to your `onEdit` script. Look at my updated answer. And, see what happens.